# How to change project url in django

Tags: django, django-deployment

I want to deploy a project in with the base url `www.example.com/project_name`. How can I achieve this? I can successfully deploy it to `www.example.com`, but I need to deploy it in first way.

**edit**:
I'm using gunicorn for production and running following command
`gunicorn project_name.wsgi:application --timeout 600 --workers 10 --log-level=debug --reload --bind=0.0.0.0:9090`

Nginx Entry is:

```
location /project_name {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.101:9090;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    }
```

Comment: Post your urls.py file

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. How are you deploying it? What server software are you using?

Comment: @Lara the urls have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood! I thought he was trying just to change from / to /project_name. So, maybe is something about nginx for example..

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added details about gunicorn

Comment: See [this blog post](http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2011/Sep/15/hosting-django-under-different-locations).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I got my basic site working, but still static files are downloaded from old url `/static/css/` instead of `/project_name/static/css`.

Comment: Well, the static files are served by nginx, surely. You can edit the alias right there in your nginx config, and set STATIC_URL in your Django settings to match it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting `SCRIPT_NAME` in nginx directives.

```
location /project_name {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.101:9090;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /project_name;
    proxy_set_header PATH_INFO /project_name;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
}
```